# php: Retrieve binary file from POST request

Tags: php, post, download, httprequest, httpresponse

is there any way to retrieve binary data file send as response for POST request?

I.e. You customize your package in some page, than click Submit and HTTP server resposne for this POST request with ZIP archive.

I know that I can send POST request with cURL, but whats next to do? How to retrieve this file?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to `file_put_contents()` on the response of the curl request?

Comment: not file_get_contents()?

Comment: If you want to save it, it's file_put_contents (putting the output to a file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cURL to send the POST request (I'm not showing that part of the code, you said you know how to do that). The returned response will be the contents of the ZIP file. You can then save it in a local file, or send it to the client; I show the first option below.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
...
$result = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents("foo.zip", $result);
```

You can also use the `CURLOPT_FILE` option to write directly to the file instead of using a variable first:

```
$fh = fopen("foo.zip", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
close($fh);
```

Comment: How would you catch this attachment then in the success function of an AJAX call?

Comment: @cars10 You wouldn't. This is intended as the response to a normal form submission. The browser will then pop up a file save dialogue.

Comment: Ahh, life can be so easy if you (in this case *I*) read the question properly! ;-))

Comment: No no no, it's not what i mean. I know that if MY SERVER wonna serv file to client than yes - this is good answer. But ANOTHER SERVER is sending to MY SERVER file as attachment, and I wonna to MY SERVER download it.

Comment: Do you want to download it locally on the server, or send it back to the original client?

Comment: When you use `curl`, the response data will be the contents of the file that the other server sends.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to have the server put this Zip archive together and then send the link in the Post response back.

Comment: Well, this was assuming, that the `POST` was used in an AJAX request. So ... forget about it! ;-)